# Revoked certificate is still valid by Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, openssl, crl, ocsp

I have generated Self-Signed Certificate, `Root-CA` Signed by `Root-CA`

Then, `Intermediate-CA` Signed by `Root-CA` and `Server` Signed by `Intermediate-CA`

The certificates as given below:

```
Root-CA  ->  Intermediate-CA  ->  Server

Root-CA:
rootca.key
rootca.crt
rootca.crl

Intermediate-CA:
intermediateca.key
intermediateca.crt
intermediateca.crl

Server:
server.key
server.crt
```

Nginx conf:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 SSL;
        server_name www.example.com;

        ssl_certificate  /home/user/confs/server+intermediateca.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/user/confs/server.key;

        ssl_ocsp on;
        ssl_crl /home/user/confs/intermediateca+rootca.crl;

        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /home/user/confs/intermediateca+rootca.crt;
}
```

Using this configure, If I revoke `server.crt` OCSP Response shows certificate is Revoked and Firefox Browser shows error of revoked certificate but in the Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge browser there is no warning, I am getting access with the revoked certificate, why? What is going wrong? Google Chrome uses `CRLsets`, how can I configure in a proper way? Can anyone please help me with this?

`Is there any proper way to config that will show error revoked certificate in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge? How to add revoked certificat in CRLsets?`

Using the below command, I am getting an error:

```
openssl verify -extended_crl -crl_check_all -crl_download -CAfile intermediateca+rootca.pem -verbose server.crt
```

Output:

```
Unable to load CRL via CDP
40971A29A97F0000:error:1E80006E:HTTP routines:OSSL_HTTP_REQ_CTX_nbio:missing asn1 encoding:../crypto/http/http_client.c:755:
40971A29A97F0000:error:1E800067:HTTP routines:OSSL_HTTP_REQ_CTX_exchange:error receiving:../crypto/http/http_client.c:874:server=http://www.example.com:80
C = BD, ST = Dhaka, O = Example, CN = www.example.com
error 3 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get certificate CRL
error server.crt: verification failed
```

`What is the above error I am getting? How can I fix that error?`

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox checks CRLs, whereas Chrome/Chromium/Edge does not.  The latter use [CRLSets](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/crlsets/) instead.

There is a good table at the bottom of [this article](https://www.ssl.com/blogs/how-do-browsers-handle-revoked-ssl-tls-certificates/).  However it's 18 months old, and as browser security is a moving target, by the time you read it things may have changed :-)

OpenSSL does check CRLs, which is why the revocation checks work for you there.

Comment: This is not I am asking for.  See the question above, please.

Comment: From the linked page: _The Chromium source code that implements CRLSets is, of course, public. But the process by which they are generated is not._  That says to me that you cannot simply add your own certificates to the CRLSets.

Comment: Any idea about the error `unable to get certificate CRL` it is not working with `crl_download`.

Comment: What have you got as the CRL Distribution Point in your intermediate CA and server certificates? It should be an URL pointing to the relevant CRL.

Comment: In Root-CA cert's `crlDistributionPoints` to `rootca.crl`. In Intermediate-CA cert's `crlDistributionPoints` to `intermediateca.crl`. Server cert's `crlDistributionPoints` to `intermediateca.crl`.

Comment: How does it point?  What scheme? HTTP? LDAP? FTP? https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280.html#section-4.2.1.13

Comment: `crlDistributionPoints=URI:http://www.example.com/crl/intermediateca.crl`

Comment: And is your CRL downloadable from that URL? `curl http://www.example.com/crl/intermediateca.crl`

Comment: Yes, it is downloadable. `curl http://www.example.com/crl/intermediateca.crl`

Comment: And the root CRL?  Please note that Server Fault isn't a site where others do your basic investigation work for you.  It is a site for _professional_ IT admins.

Comment: Both `http://www.example.com/crl/rootca.crl` and `http://www.example.com/crl/intermediateca.crl` are downloadable. I am here just trying to find the solution. This is not a basic problem. If you ask me basic questions then the answers will be basic. Ask all your questions in one comment, don't make sub section. Note: `This comment section looks like a chat section, not behave like professional IT admins`, please try to maintain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138667/discussion-between-soup-and-gareththered).